# Cannot access a nested array within an object in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

[image: My redux state hierarchy]

Hello, I am new to redux and I am struggling with a problem. I am trying to access and map over the comments within my post array. However, I am not sure how to do this. So far, I've tried changing the actions and reducers in order to solve this issue. I think the problem is within the react and redux. I can't tell if my mapStateToProps is working correctly.  Also, the state is being fetched from my express server and it seems to be working properly as you can see in the picture.

My getPost action:

```
export const getPost = (group_id, post_id) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/groups/${group_id}/${post_id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.statusText, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

The initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  groups: [],
  group: [],
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};
```

The reducer:

```
case GET_POST:
  return {
  ...state,
  post: payload,
  loading: false
};
```

Where I'm trying to map over the comments:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPost } from '../../../redux/actions/group';

const Post = ({ getPost, post, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPost(match.params.group_id, match.params.post_id);
  }, [getPost, match.params.group_id, match.params.post_id]);

  // I want to map over the comments here
  return (
      {post.comments.map(comment => ({ comment }))}
  );
};

Post.propTypes = {
  getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  group: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPost })(Post);
```

Comment: The coments seems to be an array of objects. Can you update the structure of that object and what are trying to display. And FYI we can't display an object.

Comment: Hello, @Vishnu. I am trying to display the post. The post will have comments replying to it. Basically, I am trying to display all of the comments of the post if you click on the post.

Comment: I got that, but the comment is not a string. So if the shape of comment is like `{comment: 'foo', author:'bar'}` You can iterate over it like `{post.comments.map(comment => (<div>comment: {comment.comment} {comment.author}</div> ))}`, PS: based on how you want the layout :v

Comment: @Vishnu I was trying to do it that way before but it gave me TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined. I don't think I can access post unless I go through group.

Comment: The initialState is missing posts. You can initialize post with `{}` and add a check in return statement like `{post.comments && post.comments.map(....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access nested object with some tricks using redux, we have use this way in our prod env for some time.

First the reducer (you can make this reducer even more complex)

```
const LocalStorageReducer = createReducer<Store['localStorage']>(
  new LocalStorage(),
  {
    saveLocalStorageItem(state: LocalStorage, action: any) {
      return {...state, [action.payload.item]: action.payload.value}; // <= here
    },
  }
);
```

For Actions

```
export const actions = {
  saveLocalStorageItem: (payload: InputAction) => ({type: 'saveLocalStorageItem', payload}),
};
```

For the type `InputAction`

```
export class InputAction {
  item: string;
  value: string | Array<string> | null | boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.item = '';
    this.value = null;
  }
}
```

For the handler in component

```
this.props.saveLocalStorage({ item: 'loading', value: false });
```

In this way you can go one way done to the nested redux store.
For complex (4-5 levels) and multiple (> 2 times) data structure, there are other ways, but in most situations, it's good enough.